# Document.Ready() is not working after PostBack

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a page that contains a user control within an update panel. `$(document).ready(function() ) {` is called and executes the code correctly when the page firsts loads but if the user clicks a button (within the user control), the `document.ready()` doesn't get called (`document.load`, `onload` also don't work)

I have researched this on the net and found similar problems but nothing that can explain why this isn't working. What other causes can there be for `document.ready` not working?

Comment: This could be several things.  Have any code to share?

Comment: Xyan is right, I found a different dev had added a clause which checked the url path but the casing on the url was being ignore, my code wasn't being reached. I recommend adding alerts to your JS to ensure its not being called and work from there.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will be a problem with [partial postback](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax). The DOM isn't reloaded and so the document ready function won't be hit again. You need to assign a partial postback handler in JavaScript like so...

```
function doSomething() {
   //whatever you want to do on partial postback
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(doSomething);
```

The above call to `add_endRequest` should be placed in the JavaScript which is executed when the page first loads.

Comment: It should be `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(doSomething);`

Comment: Is the 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager' C# or javascript?

Comment: It's Javascript - it's a routine of the Microsoft Ajax JS libraries which are loaded

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Sorry - that's because I'd put `doSomething()` as the argument to `add_endRequest` - I believe that `add_endRequest` only accepts a single function reference as argument. Obviously putting `doSomething()` as the argument would pass the return value of `doSomething` to `add_endRequest`...

Comment: This is not working. Where should I need to put this?

Comment: @Krunal It needs to go in JavaScript which is executed when the page first loads

Comment: @ElRonnoco I'm working on an asp.net MVC application. Should I put this on root template?

Comment: @Krunal - I'm not sure about that, I don't do MVC I'm afraid. I don't even know if you will have `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` in an MVC project. Your issues sounds like it could be completely different. I would advise posting a new question.

Comment: @ElRonnoco Thanks for your response. I already posted it here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453249/jquery-range-slider-not-working-after-ajax-call-after-updating-jquery-to-1-10-2?noredirect=1#comment36052556_23453249

Comment: BeginRequest worked for me instead: 

window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(**Javascript function here **)

Answer (score 31):

Instead of `$(document).ready` you could use  `function pageLoad(){}`.

It's automatically called by the `ScriptManager` on a page, even on a postback.

Comment: function pageLoad() doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: and you have an `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />` on the page?

Comment: Yes, the page has a ScriptManager

Answer (score 17):

I've run into this a while ago, as El Ronnoco said, it has to go with the DOM not being reloaded.  However you can simply change
`$(document).ready(function() {`
to

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
```

This will force it to run on every postback.

You can use function pageLoad() as well, but you can only have one pageLoad function, whereas with Sys.Application.add_load, you can add as many handlers as you wish.

Comment: Hi dcreight, in the page add the following:
`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/path/to/file.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>`
Then in the external file (file.js), do the following:
`Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
  //insert code here to do on every postback
});`
The problem with using the `function pageLoad() {}` approach is that you can only have one of these in a page, vs my approach above you can add as many add_load functions as you want. If you still have trouble please send the error or sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Needed it for jQueryUI Accordion in an UpdatePanel. Was trying for hours until I found this.

Answer (score 10):

Bestest way is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel...
<ContentTemplate
     <script type="text/javascript">
                    Sys.Application.add_load(LoadScript);
     </script>
 you hemla code gose here 
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function LoadScript() {
            $(document).ready(function() {

                   //you code gose here 
                                    });
         }
</script>
```

or

Its under UpdatePanel than you need to register client script again using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScript
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind your jQuery events here initially
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    // re-bind your jQuery events here
    loadscript();

});


$(document).ready(loadscript);

function loadscript()
{
  //yourcode 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean register the javascript I want to excutue again?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser - yes liket that or as suggested in below answer you can do it easily

Answer (score 3):

This is an example that worked for me in the past:

```
<script>
function MyFunction(){ 
    $("#id").text("TESTING");
}
//Calling MyFunction when document is ready (Page loaded first time)
$(document).ready(MyFunction); 

//Calling MyFunction when the page is doing postback (asp.net)
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MyFunction);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code below works nice to solve this problem. As indicated in link posted before (http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/), when you have an asp.NET with updatePanels you shall use function pageLoad(). When you have only one page and in each postback it will be fully reloaded, the $(document).ready() is the right option.

Example using pageLoad:

```
    function pageLoad() {

        $(".alteraSoVirgula").keyup(function () {
            code here
        })
    }
```

Comment: Your answer does touch on some of the same ideas as the other answers that have been submitted(and the accepted answer) but it contains a lot of extra fluff that is specific to wherever you originally wrote this code. To get more positive feedback on your answer I would suggest removing anything that is not specific to the question being asked and add an explanation as to _why_ your solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, very nice job.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem but i found the jQuery $(document).ready event handler works when page loads, but after ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel Partial PostBack it does not get called. so use Sys.Application.add_load(function(){}); instead of $(document).ready.
This works perfectly for me :)

`<script>

     Sys.Application.add_load(function() {
         //Your code
     });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PreRoles();
});

//On UpdatePanel Refresh
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            PreRoles();
        }
    });
};

function PreRoles() {
    // Add codes that should be called on postback
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Most of the times, this is happening because of the Updatepanle. 
Just put **postback triggers** to the button and it will solve this.