# Document Ready not working after file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Aspx page.
On button Click i am downloading a file from server.

**Server side code for downloading a file.**

```
   byte[] data = GetBytes();
    //Sets the Content Type and FileName 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "plan/text";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",  string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Error.txt"));

    //Writes the Content in HttpResponse
    //to enable downloading the file.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

**Javascript code on Aspx page.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 alert(1);
});
```

This alert is getting shown on the first page load.
But it not showing the alert after the postback for file download.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most probably you might not have a post back

Comment: @SubinJacob yes the page request is getting canceled when the file is downloaded. Is their any way i can fire a javascript method after downlaod complete ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **[Partial Postback](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)**. you need to use `PageRequestManager` to setup a request handler. The request handler will then execute on partial postback too.

**[See This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels)**

**[See This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586903/document-ready-is-not-working-after-postback)**

Comment: I am not using any UpdatePanel or ScriptManager.

Comment: Try removing respose.end in code behind. lets see if it works.

Comment: No effect after removing the Response.End();

Comment: Then i would recommend writing a function explicitly and calling it in call behind. and call this function on clientclick with some setinterval.