# A timepicker javascript stops working when the page does postback ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, timepicker, autopostback

I have an update panel in my page.aspx, and inside the update panel I have textbox with bootstrap timepicker, I show an example:

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="upd1">
                <ContentTemplate>
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
                        <label class="control-label">Monday</label>                            
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker input-sm">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFecIni_1" class="form-control input-small "></asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker input-sm">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFecFin_1" class="form-control input-small "></asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

              </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Under the `</ form>` of my page I add this javascript code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
  $('#txtFecIni_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });

            $('#txtFecFin_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });
}

    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
```

The timepicker works properly until an object is thrown autopostback. How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem at this way:

I change  `window.onload = function ()` for `function pageLoad()`
like that:

**Before:**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
  $('#txtFecIni_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });

            $('#txtFecFin_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });
}

    </script>
```

**After:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          function pageLoad() {
  $('#txtFecIni_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });

            $('#txtFecFin_1').timepicker({
                minuteStep: 30,
                defaultTime: false,
                showMeridian: false
            });
}

    </script>
```

I read that the  Pageload is called on every postback.
Hopefully this will be helpful to someone

Answer (score 0):

this is due to postback of asp.net control [here is explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586903/document-ready-is-not-working-after-postback)

Use `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManage`

and your code will be something like this..

```
<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                       $('#txtFecIni_1').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 30,
                    defaultTime: false,
                    showMeridian: false
                });

                $('#txtFecFin_1').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 30,
                    defaultTime: false,
                    showMeridian: false
                    });
              });
                var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                prm.add_endRequest(function () {


                       $('#txtFecIni_1').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 30,
                    defaultTime: false,
                    showMeridian: false
                });

                $('#txtFecFin_1').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 30,
                    defaultTime: false,
                    showMeridian: false
                    });
                });
            </script>
```